# Restore a NTFS volume back up by Disk Utility

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, ntfs

I have a Windows installation which I created with Bootcamp. Then I need to expand the volume to add more Software. So I use Disk Utility to create a DMG image for the Bootcamp volume. But after I have deleted the old Bootcamp volume and create a new larger volume, I cannot restore it with Disk Utility:

[image]

Nor asr:

```
 asr restore --source /Users/phuongnd08/Downloads/BOOTCAMP.dmg  --target /dev/disk0s3 --erase --noverify
    Validating target...done
    Validating source...done
    Erase contents of /dev/disk0s3 ()? [ny]: y
    Repartitioning target device...
Could not change the partition type for /dev/disk0s3 - Operation not permitted
```

I guess due to NTFS? But this sounds very illogical because: you can create image out of it, you should be able to restore it from an image? What should I do now to restore that image?

Comment: The command might need a `sudo`. Have you tried restoring while booted to macOS Recovery? Did you try mounting DMG before doing the restore? Did you "scan the image for restore" after creating the DMG?

Comment: I did "scan the image for restore.". I try mounting DMG before the restore but getting another error. I haven't tried restoring while booted to macOS Recovery. I'm not sure why do I need to boot into Recovery because the restore happens on a separate volume?

Comment: I assume you need to run `asr` as root user or you need to run with SIP disabled. This is why I suggested `sudo` and booting to Recovery.